# localStorage - Delete local|Storage value based on key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am facing some problem in deleting localStorage json data. I have passed data in JSON format and want to delete value based on ID on click event. For example in JSON array if I have three entries of same id then want to delete three at a time.

here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var feed = {"proid":"2","canvas":"abc"};

a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names')) || [];

names = JSON.stringify(feed);

a.push(names);

localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(a));

var obj = "["+a+"]"; 

localStorage.setItem("productidf", obj);

$('#delete-item').click(function(){

var jsonprodId = localStorage.getItem("productidf"); 

  var parsedJSON =  $.parseJSON(jsonprodId);
  var id = 2;

for(var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++){
  if(parsedJSON[i].proid == id){
     localStorage.removeItem(parsedJSON[i]);
  }
}

localStorage.setItem("productidf", JSON.stringify(parsedJSON));
var newss = localStorage.getItem("productidf");

console.log(newss);
});
});




</script>

<a class="clicks" id="delete-item">Delete Items</a>
```

This code is not working to remove all values of id from localStorage. I can't use localStorage.clear(). Because it clear all localstorage.

Comment: Where is your click event function?

Comment: I have updated my question. Now you can check click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `localStorage.removeItem(parsedJSON[i]);` line was the culprit.
`localstorage` cannot be traversed like an array. It just stores data in string format.

So you need to filter `parsedJSON` array using a js `filter` and then store the result back in localStorage

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-

latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var feed = {"proid":"2","canvas":"abc"};
var feed2={"proid":"3","canvas":"jack"}

a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names')) || [];
a.push(feed);
a.push(feed2);

localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(a));


localStorage.setItem("productidf", JSON.stringify(a));
var jsonprodId = localStorage.getItem("productidf"); 

  var parsedJSON =  $.parseJSON(jsonprodId);
  var id = 2;

parsedJSON=parsedJSON.filter((obj)=>{
   return obj.proid != id;
})

debugger
var obj = JSON.stringify(parsedJSON);
localStorage.setItem("productidf", obj);
console.log(parsedJSON);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is not any way to remove the matched id data from localStorage??

Comment: I just did, removed the id matched data from your localStorage. Check localStorage value

Comment: Yes. I have checked. After Id filter it displays the values that are not matched with id. But somehow i want to remove the matched values permanently Is not possible ?

Comment: You want to remove matched values from where? localStorage or parsedJSON

Comment: I want to remove the matched values from localstorage.

Comment: for which key? `names` or `productidf` in localstorage.
I removed it for `productidf` key

Comment: localStorage.setItem("productidf", obj);
I want to remove the matched values that are stored in productidf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177895/discussion-between-sandeep-sidhu-and-helping-hand).